# Remove legend for points in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I'm following this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_highlight.html, and added text points. My lines have both strokeDash and color.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

highlight = alt.selection(type='single', on='mouseover',
                          fields=['symbol'], nearest=True)

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='price:Q',
    color='symbol:N',
    strokeDash='symbol:N'
)

points = base.mark_circle().encode(
    opacity=alt.value(0)
).add_selection(
    highlight
).properties(
    width=600
)

lines = base.mark_line().encode(
    size=alt.condition(~highlight, alt.value(1), alt.value(3))
)

points + lines
```

I'd like the legend to only show the dashed and colored lines, not the others (legend for text and points iiuc)

Is it possible to completely remove the extra legends from a chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to explicitly remove the legend on `points` and `text` by setting the `color` and `strokeDash` attributes

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

highlight = alt.selection(type='single', on='mouseover',
                          fields=['symbol'], nearest=True)

base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='price:Q',
    color='symbol:N',
    strokeDash='symbol:N'
)

points = base.mark_point().encode(
    opacity=alt.value(0),
    color=alt.Color('symbol:N', legend=None),
    strokeDash=alt.StrokeDash('symbol:N', legend=None)
).add_selection(
    highlight
).properties(
    width=600
)

lines = base.mark_line().encode(
    size=alt.condition(~highlight, alt.value(1), alt.value(3))
)

text = lines.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=7
).encode(
    text='symbol',
    color=alt.Color('symbol:N', legend=None),
    strokeDash=alt.StrokeDash('symbol:N', legend=None)
)

(lines + points + text).resolve_scale(color='independent', strokeDash='independent')
```